# Android app for fine gestion of internet rights

Tags: android, data

I'm looking for a software that would monitor and control my bandwidth usage under android.

What's important to me is that:

- It separates WiFi and data from my carrier.
- It allows me to allocate a specific amount of data for each app.
- It prevents any other app from using data if not in the chosen source.

It would be enjoyable if the interface was nice to use, but I don't care much if it is long to set up.

I would prefer if the application weren't root, but I'm open to suggestions that are.

Comment: The second requirement will be the show-stopper I'm afraid: Never heard of an app providing that. If a solution covering the other two requirements would be acceptable, I might have some apps to name. In that case, please [edit] your question and include whether "root" is available.

Comment: It's actually this last point that made me ask this question. I would prefer if the application weren't root, but I'm open to suggestions that are.